How to retrieve specific columns from the Inventory table using getPropertiesDt()?
I am working with Autodesk Tandem and have implemented a custom app where a facility and its associated view are displayed. Now I want to retrieve all columns from the Inventory table.
Here is my current code:
await app.displayFacility(matchingFacility, aModelIds, viewer);
await app.views.setCurrentView(matchingFacility, matchingView);
const viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D = this.oViewer;
const model: Autodesk.Viewing.Model = viewer.model;
const visibleDbIds = await model.getVisibleDbIds();
const inventoryElements: = await model.getPropertiesDt(visibleDbIds);

This works fine, except for a few specific columns that are missing:

[Common][Category Name]
[Common][SourceFile]

My questions are:

Is there documentation for the optional parameters of getPropertiesDt()?
How can I ensure that the above-mentioned columns are included in the results?


Here is full signature of the method:
DtModel.getPropertiesDt(dbIds: number[], options?: {
  classificatioID?: string;
  history?: boolean;
  includeDeleted?: boolean;
  intersect?: boolean;
  wantTimeSeries?: boolean;
}): Promise<any[]>;

The inventory component is actually using different method to get properties:
DtModel.query({
  includes?: {
        standard?: boolean;
        applied?: boolean;
        element?: boolean; 
        type?: boolean;
        id?: boolean;
    };
    compositeChildren?: boolean;
    dbIds: number[];
}): Promise<{ rows: any[]; cols: any[]; }>;

which returns same data but using different structure (more suitable for our grid component). There is also some postprocessing when we add additional columns based on the inventory context.
